# Preprocessor directives in linux makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, c-preprocessor

How do you use commands like #define and !include in linux makefile for the g++ compiler? 
My understanding is that # creates a comment line so wont #define just be a comment?
Thanks for the help

Comment: You don't put those in the makefile. You put them in the `.c`/`.cc`/`.cxx`/etc. files.

Comment: Im not looking to change the .cpp files as much as possible, Im looking to change the equivalent of !IFDEF and !INCLUDE, I edited the question

Comment: You want to define values on the command line? That's `-D`. You can also include files from the command line with `-include` I believe.

Comment: if you really want to use a '#' then escape it with backslash ... i.e.: `\#define`

Answer (score 0):

I typically define a variable at the top of the file, and set it equal to the `#define` values I want like this:

```
DEFINES=-DSOMETHING -DSOMETHING_ELSE
```

For includes, `g++` accepts search paths from the command line with `-I`.
For the makefile you can do the same thing, just make a variable and add the paths:

```
INCLUDES=-I/path -I/path2
```

The makefile then just calls the compiler as

```
g++ $(DEFINES) $(INCLUDES) file.cpp
```

Comment: Terminology nitpick: only newbies call it DEFINES. The correct word is "MACROS". Or would you also say "fors" instead of "loops"?

Comment: Yes, just keeping consistent terms with OP.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example

```
# I am a comment, and I want to say that the variable CC will be
# the compiler to use.
CC=g++
# Hey!, I am comment number 2. I want to say that CFLAGS will be the
# options I'll pass to the compiler.
CFLAGS=-c -Wall

all: hello

hello: main.o factorial.o hello.o
    $(CC) main.o factorial.o hello.o -o hello

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.cpp

factorial.o: factorial.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) factorial.cpp

hello.o: hello.cpp
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) hello.cpp

clean:
    rm *o hello
```

for more information check these:

http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/

http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2002/cmsc214/Tutorial/makefile.html

Comment: Please [edit] with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are [discouraged](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187), because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.